# mean value theorem $f'(\xi)=\frac 1\xi$?

Tags: calculus

As the solution to a problem in an old test paper i have seen an application of the Mean Value theorem where they state

$$f'(\xi)=\frac 1\xi={f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}$$

I don't follow the $f'(\xi)=\frac 1\xi$ part or see why this is valid.

Cheers

Andy

Comment: That would be true if $f(x)=\log(x)$

Comment: Yep, thanks, I just realised this myself.